# extJs Display field not showing image

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I written some code for displaying user image.
I want to show user image after selecting/browsing it on local machine but it not shows after browse. below I placed some code for better understand.

```
this.userPhoto = new Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {
            xtype: 'filefield',
            padding: '5 5 5',
            cls: 'p-photo-upload',
            emptyText: 'Photo',
            buttonOnly: true,
            fieldLabel: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERDETAIL_PHOTO_'),
            name: 'photo',
            labelWidth: 200,
            width: '26%',
            msgTarget: 'under',
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                change: function (t, value) {
                    var img = '<img src="' + t.getValue() + '" />';
                    console.log('image', img, value, t.getRawValue());
                    //var img = '<img src="' + FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/users/DefaultUserIcon.jpg' + '" />';
                    this.userimage.setValue(img);
                }
            }
        });
```

above code I use for browse user image. change event in listener set the image file path to Display field (Display field Code placed below)

```
  this.userimage = new Ext.form.field.Display({
            labelWidth: 200,
            cls: 'p-uploaded-icon',
            width: '28%',
            height: 70,
            labelAlign: 'right',
            autoShow: true,
            autoRender: true,
            fieldLabel: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERDETAIL_ICON_'),
            value: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERDETAIL_NOICON_')
            //value: '<img src="' + FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'appRes/images/user.jpg' + '/>'
        });
```

after selecting image its show path like this img src="C:\fakepath\boy.png" but image not shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [@Tyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4066269/) is right regarding the allowance of accessing files from Javascript due to security reasons, for your purpose (I understood it as displaying an image thumbnail before uploading it to the server) there is an option, and it's called [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

> Since we emulate as much of HTML5 as possible, we are able (among other things) to provide access to raw file data, even in such environments that do not normally support it. One of the biggest benefits of this is that we can display the thumbnails instantly, right as you select the images in the dialog or drag&drop them from the desktop.

I myself have implemented this a while a go in a project. [Here](https://github.com/bennadel/Plupload-Image-Preview) is a repository that I've found that you can look into to see how it is done. There are also [some](https://gist.github.com/shuLhan/2827463) [ExtJS](https://github.com/harrydeluxe/extjs-ux/tree/master/ux/upload) integrations with plupload that you can get something useful from.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to show files directly via javascript before upload due to security reasons.

Comment: But is there any option?

Comment: No, the access to the local file system is restricted. On select, you can upload the image to a temporary directory and set the path to the uploaded file as an alternative way.

Comment: Ok. Thank you :)